# how make combination n^n in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want data just as show in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHsW3.jpg).
This is n^n results. Here V1,V2 & V3 show as column name.
[image]

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want to pivot `Vendors` and then do a `CROSS JOIN` against Products.

Comment: yes. But second table column value insert with comma in one column as show in image

Comment: Avoid using links that might go 404 in the future.

Comment: Looks like you want all permutations of 2 sets, where NULL is part of each set and excluding the permutation where all elements are NULL. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- DROP TABLE Vendors, Products
CREATE TABLE Vendors (Vendor VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE Products (Product VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Vendors VALUES ('V1'),('V2'),('V3')
INSERT INTO dbo.Products VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3')

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)=(
    SELECT 'SELECT '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),(
        SELECT ','+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),(
            SELECT '+CASE WHEN P'+Product+'='''+Vendor+''' THEN '''+Product+''' ELSE '''' END'
            FROM dbo.Products
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        )),2,8000)+' AS '+Vendor
        FROM dbo.Vendors
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
     )),2,8000)
    +' FROM '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),(
        SELECT ',(VALUES '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),(
            SELECT ',('''+Vendor+''')'
            FROM dbo.Vendors
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        )),2,8000)+') P'+Product+' (P'+Product+')'
        FROM dbo.Products
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )),2,8000)
)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Razvan

Comment: @AkhileshKumarGupta Try understand the solution, and then adapt it to incorporate extra requirements. StackOverflow is not a board to do all the work for you.